# Is there a Time data type in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to convert times in string format "HH:mm:ss" (ie. 23:15:20) from an on-premise database to parquet files using PySpark. There seems to be no Time datatype to do this. What would be the best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try using timestamp type. The date will be set to 1970-01-01.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to compare the time, then you can use `TimestamptType` and ignore its date, it will cover the time for you. Otherwise, if there is no reason of converting it to timestamp, then you can always parse it as string using regex.

Comment: thanks for your input. I have a weird dataset from a weird database. They hold the dates in number format in certain columns and time in number format in another. I was looking for a proper way to convert them in the parquet files but it looks like it's not possible to keep them seperate.

Comment: In that case, you can reformat the time, then `concat` with the date, and finally cast it all to DateType. How about that?